# Visual Studio Community 2015 JavaScript Console grayed out

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2015, javascript-debugger

I simply have an empty web project with 1 html file, 1 css file, and 1 JavaScript file.  I saw a tutorial where the guy was debugging in VS in a JavaScript console window... like you see in most browser's dev tools.

I F5 to debug my project and go to Debug > Windows > JavaScript Console .. and it is grayed out.  Do I have to set something up first or am I missing a component?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that the JavaScript console option is only available when I am debugging using Internet Explorer.  I was using Chrome.  I guess that makes sense.